# How to get variable from Javascript function in C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm a beginner of C#.

Question: I'm trying to retrieve a variable `area` from Javascript function `compute_shape_area()`, how do I implement in C# asp.net? Thanks a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>test</title>     
  </head>

 <body onload="compute_shape_area()">
  <p id="area1"></p>
 <script>
  var Obj_shape;

  function initMap() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/shape.txt');         
    //GET Data and build Obj_shape
    request.send();
  }

  function compute_shape_area(){ 
    var area = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(Obj_shape.getPath()));
    area = area.toFixed(4);

    document.getElementById("area1").innerHTML = area;
  }

 </script>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&callback=initMap"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `asp:HiddenField` variables to share values between code behind in C# and your JavaScript code (viewstateapproch during  postbacks).

Or you could use the following code:

`<script type="text/javascript"> var yourJsVariable= '<%=yourJsVariable%>'</script>`

Comment: excuse me, where should I place this script ?? here is an error : The name 'yourJsVariable' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @HenryWenHanLee code in my answer was only an illustrative example in order to order to show the principal :) you should change it using your real code app. In your case consider asp:HiddenField to be retrieved on postback